# Is there a way to tell if I've sold anything during my current playthrough?

Tags: achievements, south-park-the-stick-of-truth

In the game South Park: The Stick of Truth, there is an achievement called `For the Hoarder` that you earn if you successfully go through one playthrough of the game without selling *anything*, including junk.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to tell if you have accidentally sold anything back to a vendor? Or whether the achievement is still active?

Comment: No; There isn't; Just don't visit vendors

Comment: is there a way to get this "For the Hoarder" achievement as well as the "Junk Peddler" achievement?  Perhaps after the end boss is there an open world option that you can return with all your loot and sell off the 300 pieces of junk needed for the "Junk Peddler"?

Comment: I am not familiar with the requirements for that secondary achievement

Comment: i did some more research on an xbox forum, sounds like there is post-game play where you can get the Junk Peddler after achieving For the Hoarder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Ramhound in the comments, **no**, there simply isn't a way to know this.

However, it's worth noting that not only selling items will lock you out of this achievement. According to multiple posts in this thread, exchanging currencies counts as a transaction and will prevent you from getting the `For the Hoarder` achievement.

> You don't need to complete all side missions, just not sell anything at all in the game, **including currency exchange.**
>
> I did the same thing on my first run, the Canadian currency exchange got me. Can't believe that counts as a sale. I was so focused on getting all the equipment at the Canadian stores that I never even stopped to think that that could be counted as selling.

---

If you think you may have just accidentally sold an item to a vendor, reload your last save. It seems like the autosave tends to kick in after boss fights and during map transitions, but I can't confirm whether or not completing transactions with vendors will trigger it too.

Thus, to be absolutely certain you don't accidentally lock yourself out of this achievement, the best thing to do would be to create a separate manual save prior to every time you interact with a vendor. That way you'll have a way to backup if you accidentally sell something to them.

Comment: the problem i faced was that i stepped away from the game for so long before coming back to it and trying out all the achievements. i wasn't confident that i hadn't sold anything so i ended up starting a new game.